# Dependent attributes in Backbone.js model

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

If either of two values - a or b - change in my model, two of the listening views need to calculate a third value c.

```
//Pseudo 
mainModel 
  a : 2000 
  b : 3000

view1 
helper.calculateC(this.model.get(a), this.model.get(b)) 

view2 
helper.calculateC(this.model.get(a), this.model.get(b))
```

I'd rather put the dependent attribute c in the model (as the 
calculation is rather complex and "c" might later on be allowed to be 
overridden by the user.) What is good practice? Should I extend the 
model, make a submodel or what?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a binding on the [model](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-change) to its own change event on the initialize call.

```
initialize: function() {
  this.bind("change", this.calculateC);
},

calculateC: function() {
  this.c = //fill in the blanks
}
```

More specifically, you can bind only on the attributes you need.

```
  this.bind("change:a", this.calculateC);
  this.bind("change:b", this.calculateC);
```

Comment: But then C will not be calculated before the model change events? Hence the views will not have access to the latest value of c. Or do you mean that the model can calculate this before firing change events somehow? Thanks.

Comment: The above seems to work :) But I can't understand how the model is notified before the views? (And: If I'd like to set "c" as an attribute of the model and fire change events for it, what do I do?) THANKS!

Comment: You get the event first because you are the first one to hook the change event on yourself.  Initialize gets called in the constructor, so you know you are the first to hook it...

Comment: Thanks! Follow-up: 1) What's a good way of preventing c from being calculated TWICE if both a and b are changed? 2) If c is a model attribute, can I make it fire a change event TOGETHER with a & b?