# Backbone Model: How to add custom attribute thats combines data from other attributes and stays in sync

Tags: backbone.js

When my collection is fetched, the server sends me **last_name**, **first_name** and **spouse_first_name** (and other attributes that aren't important to the question).

I'd like to be able to add an attribute called **mailing_name** that is essentially:

```
var setNameOnFormAttribute = this.get("last_name") + ", " + this.get("last_name");

if (!_.isNull(this.get("spouse_first_name")) || !_.isEmpty(this.get("spouse_first_name"))) {
setNameOnFormAttribute += " & " + this.get("spouse_first_name");
}
```

I want to make sure that if any of the base attributes (**last_name**, **first_name** and **spouse_first_name**) change for any reason the custom **mailing_name** attributes gets updated and any views that use the **mailing_name** attribute are updated.

I'm using backbone.marionette if that makes a difference.

### Edit 1

My first attempt:

```
define([
    'backbone'
],
function( Backbone ) {
    'use strict';

    /* Return a model class definition */
    return Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function (){
            console.log(this.attributes);
            
            this.bind("change:last_name", this.setNameOnFormAttribute);
            this.bind("change:first_name", this.setNameOnFormAttribute);
            this.bind("change:spouse_first_name", this.setNameOnFormAttribute);
        },

        setNameOnFormAttribute: function(){
            var name_on_form = this.get("last_name") + ", " + this.get("first_name");

            if (!_.isNull(this.get("spouse_first_name")) || !_.isEmpty(this.get("spouse_first_name"))) {
                name_on_form += " & " + this.get("spouse_first_name");
            }

            this.set("name_on_form", name_on_form);
        }
    });
});
```

The thing If ind odd is that the console.log at the beginning of the initialize function is is showing that all the attributes are already set. Thus the change event on the attributes doesn't fire, Thus I can't inject the new attribute in.

I'm probably taking the wrong approach here...

### Edit 2 to answer Bernardo's question

Its wired up with Marionette view. the collection is fetched from a composite view, the collection just has the appropriate model defined.

```
define([
    'backbone',
    'collections/tasks',
    'views/item/task',
    'views/item/tasklist_empty',
    'hbs!tmpl/layout/tasklist_tmpl'
],
function( Backbone, TasksCollection, TaskView, tasklistEmptyView, TasklistTmpl  ) {
    'use strict';

    return Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

        initialize: function() {
            this.collection = new TasksCollection();
            this.collection.bind("reset", _.bind(this.render, this));
            this.collection.fetch({ reset: true });
        },

        itemView: TaskView,
        emptyView: tasklistEmptyView,

        template: TasklistTmpl,

        itemViewContainer: ".tasks"

    });

});


define([
    'backbone',
    'moment',
    'application',
    'models/task'
],
function( Backbone, moment, App, Task ) {
    'use strict';

    /* Return a collection class definition */
    return Backbone.Collection.extend({
        initialize: function() {
        },

        comparator: function(model) {
            return moment(model.get('received_date')).unix();
        },

        model: Task,

        url: App.apiUrl + '/tasks'

    });
});
```

Comment: Some links. http://kilon.org/blog/2012/02/backbone-calculated-fields/   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849276/dependent-attributes-in-backbone-js-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**

I see you are indeed using a `fetch`, but are using the `reset` option.  If you look at the annotated code for backbone for the `add` function that is called, it basically adds `silent: true` to the options sent down stream.  This then is sent to the `_preparemodel` function and causes all of you child models in the collection to be created with `silent: true`, therefore you are seeing the attributes set, and never seeing the change event fire.  You'll need to manually raise that event on the models after the `fetch` with reset option.

As stands at this time, I think you just need to manually fire that event, and probably fix you logic in the `setmailtoname`, or what not, function to just use the `!_isEmpty` or change the short circuit or to an and.  I wouldn't add the call to set mail_to_name in the initialize because if you changed it to fetch without set, etc, it'll fire twice.

Here's a new [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NVcVf/1/) with the changes and a demo of them.  Also a sync redirect for testing.

I basically add this below to your Collection model.  There is possibly a better way, but I've only been looking at backbone for a few days.

```
initialize: function () {
    this.bind("reset", function () {
        _.each(this.models, function (model) {
            model.setNameOnFormAttribute.apply(model, arguments);
        });
    });
```

**End of Edit: The rest is just information.**

I'm assuming this data is not coming from a `fetch`, or something, since you are checking the attributes in the `initialize` function?  That wouldn't be executed on a `fetch`, right?

**Assuming not:**

The events will not fire until you make a change *after* the attributes are mapped, so I called the `setNameOnForm` in the `initialize` function.  In the code provided, I set the `options` to `{ silent: true }` so that the "change" trigger is not sent, but you may want to remove that based on your usage.

**Assuming it is fetched**

Could the function to set be wrong?  Can you log in there to see if it is called and if it is returning the right values?  I think the function should be the one below.  You may have an issue with the `||` rather than a `&&`

**jsfiddle**

I also added the ability to handle the `options` parameter [called either directly or passed in from the call to a observed set [ex. `aModel.set("last_name");`] which is then sent to the method as the third argument via the `Backbone.Model.trigger` function.

I stuck a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NVcVf/) up with a little hacky logging.  I do not know how to use marionette, sorry.  I haven't updated it with the function change.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Backbone source here:

http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-28

you can see that the model attributes are set in the Backbone.Model constructor before initialize is called.

That's however unrelated to the change event not firing in your case: your change event should fire after the model's data is fetched from the server, and your bindings should trigger the composite property to be set.

Your code looks right so far - how are you initializing the model, the view, and fetching the data?

Comment: Its wired up with Marionette. I have a composite view that fetches a collection in its view.